# Lagrange multiplier problem for $x^3$ on unit circle

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was asked to find max/min of $f(x,y)=x^3$ on unit circle. I attempted:

$3x^2=\lambda2x$,
$0=\lambda 2y$ if $x=0,y=\pm 1$.If $x$ is not zero $\lambda=3x/2$.

I researched answer on wolfram and received nonsensical answer. So is there an answer to this problem that is easy?

Comment: What is the min/max of $x$ on a unit circle centered at $(0,0)$? Would that be min/max of $x^3$ too?

Comment: @MathLover max of $f$ on unit circle only $x^3$.Yes center at (0,0)

Comment: That was not a question but a hint. Have you been asked to use Lagrange Multiplier method?

Comment: @MathLover yes asked to use lagrange multiplier i know it is $1$,$-1$ so the max of $f$ should be $1$ and min $-1$? how should I show it using lagrange?

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. So you started with a system of equations:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^3-\lambda(x^2+y^2-1))=0\\\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(x^3-\lambda(x^2+y^2-1))=0$$
This yields $$3x^2-2\lambda x=0\\-2\lambda y=0$$
Looking at the second equation, you can have either $\lambda=0$ or $y=0$. Notice that you will also need to use $$x^2+y^2=1$$
So if $\lambda=0$, than $x=0$ and $y=\pm1$. Then $f(x,y)=0$.

If $\lambda\ne 0$, then $y=0$. Therefore from the circle equation you get $x=\pm 1$. The corresponding values for $f(x,y)$ are $\pm 1$. So the minimum is $-1$ at $x=-1, y=0$, and the maximum is $+1$ at $x=1,y=0$. If you try to visualize this, when you draw the unit circle, the maximum of $f(x,y)$ is at the maximum value of $x$, which is $1$, when $y=0$.